# How to create multiple iOS projects with common code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Suppose that I have similar apps that share a lot of code. Paid and free versions, whitelabeled apps for different client companies, that sort of thing. In general, the differences between apps would be relatively minor; some images would be different, some text would be different, some kind of flag values would be different--the shared code would check for those values and change behavior accordingly.

A nice bonus, but not essential, would be for each app to be able to add code to extend/override some of the shared code.

I have read of several different approaches--there may be more I haven't considered.

**one .framework file used in many repositories**
I don't know much about this, but I gather it would be like making a JAR in Java; compiling code to be used as-is by other programs. This might work well for a general-purpose library to be used by many different kinds of apps, but as far as I know it is not suitable for the above purpose (correct me if I am wrong).

**one repository, one project, multiple targets**
From what I understand, this is most popular for the "one app with paid and free versions" situation, where there is only a very tiny difference between the apps produced--they are essentially the same app.

However, I don't know how flexible this is in terms of changes between the different targets. I gather it's possible to set a different .plist file for each target, and that can result in different text, flags or (through some kind of awkward workaround) different images for the apps, and that is it, correct?

I also feel uncomfortable with using one repository for multiple projects, but when they are this closely related, perhaps it doesn't matter.

**one repository, one workspace, multiple projects**
Although this seems to be a cleaner division among the projects, I'm not sure if there's a good way to separate resources for the different projects. The most logical solution would be to have different folders for resources for different projects, and include them in the workspace with only one target each--but I can't seem to do that. Apart from that, there seems to be little difference between this and the previous option.

**So, what is the right way** to make shared code for multiple projects that only have a few differences from one another? Is it one of the above methods (and if so, how do you do it?) or is it something different?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to have separate projects and a separate folder for each project.

You then bring each shared unit into the project as you need it. Shared features (most features) go in the shared units.

If you want to upgrade one project with the latest `Rest.h` and `Rest.m`, you bring it into the project folder. Maybe on the next project, you're not ready to upgrade to the latest.

You will have duplicate files (one for each project), but it allows you to update, test, and finely control each project atomically.

One repository or not, it doesn't matter, since the projects will have different folders and the shared files will be duplicated (possibly different versions in each, with the trunk having the latest shared files).

On a side note, I hope these many similar apps don't all end up in the App Store.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Marcus, but I'm not comfortable with copy and pasting code to every project. That sounds like it could make maintenance difficult.